# Pathfinding algorithm to match total cost of result with a given cost

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I am trying to write a pathfinding algorithm that will return a path between a starting node and an ending node, where each edge and each vertex are weighted with a cost, and the total cost of the path is known.

for example - time to go from A to B and time spent at B, in this case, time is the unit for the cost, and total time, i.e. 4 hours, is known and is the total final cost of the desired path.

The solution's total cost should be as close as possible to the given cost.
In the solution, a node cannot be visited twice.

my problem is, i don't know how to start tackling this problem.

My goal is to eventually try to write a routine in Javascript trying to solve this using a grid of given nodes with coordinates, where the cost of the node is given, and the cost of the edge between 2 nodes needs to be calculated on the spot.

Everything i can find online is about shortest path, paths that minimize the cost. but in my situation i want a path that matches the cost given.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is NP-hard. You can reduce traveling salesman to it, just stipulate that the target cost is the cost of visiting every node and the `n-1` edges necessary for the TSP tour.